# Hover not right when element moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a dynamic div, and I want to know when the mouse is hover this div. I tryed with `.is( ':hover' )` but doesn't work.

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p8c5ysk3/)

In the demo I have made a moving div and if I doesn't move the mouse the log is never called, but if I put manually the mouse hover the box it write always the logs.

[image: Never detected]

Never writes the log in the console.

[image: Always detected]

Always writes the log in the console, even the box is gone.

It's a bug or I have made a mistake? How can I detect the hover properly?

Comment: does onmouseover help you?
is that what you are looking for?  Could you mention what you expect a bit more clearly?

Comment: I have to know if the mouse is over an created object, still I haven't moved the mouse.

Comment: check this jsbin, does it help
<br/>http://jsbin.com/dorufe/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: It appears that the `:hover` pseudo class only updates on mouse move. You might need to compare the mouse position with the box position every time it updates to check for hover manually.

Comment: @Wishy - Doesn't work if you remain firm with the mouse

Comment: @FlabbyRabbit - there isn't another way?

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle using @Wishy's idea http://jsfiddle.net/p8c5ysk3/1/ but that appears to work in the same way. So the only alternative I can think of is what I suggested.

Comment: This is a thought for how to do something like this: you'll have to mess with the pixel to get it perfect, but it should work because you're caching the mouse position, and not waiting for the trigger of a hover event. good luck! http://jsfiddle.net/p8c5ysk3/4/

Comment: @FlabbyRabbit your idea is right but the problem is his interval is being set by setTimeout which does not provide an event. Without an event how  to check the mouse position?

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik - the only way it appears is to manually check if position of mouse is within the position_of_div+(width+height)_of_div

Answer (score 2):

You should be tracking the mouse movement with the [mousemove()](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) event and check the last known position of the mouse on the movement of the div.

Example:

**HTML & CSS:**

```
.red-box {
    display : inline-block;
    position : absolute;
    width : 50px;
    height : 50px;
    top : 10px;
    left : 0px;
    background-color : red;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="red-box"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var posX = 0;
var step = 10;
var maxX = 200;
var mouseX = -1;
var mouseY = -1;
var entered = false;
var $box = $('.red-box');

setInterval(function () {
    posX += step;
    if (posX >= maxX) 
        posX = 0;
    $box.css("left", posX);

    var top = $box.offset().top;
    if (mouseX >= posX && mouseX <= (posX + $box.width()) && mouseY >= top && mouseY <= (top + $box.height())) {
        console.log("mouse entered");
        entered = true;
    } else if (entered) {
        console.log("mouse left");
        entered = false;
    }
}, 500);

$("#wrapper").on("mousemove", function (e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX - $(this).position().left;
    mouseY = e.pageY - $(this).position().top;
}).on("mouseleave", function()
{
    mouseX = -1;
    mouseY = -1;
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p8c5ysk3/6/)**

Edit: Added a new [mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event to the wrapper.

Comment: zinned the idea is great but at the end i realized it wont work properly.
Try this in your fiddle, keep the mouse in the path of the rectange and try to move it out of the window in the same line of path that the rectangle moves. So the last stored value of mouse still points in the line of path even though the mouse is moved out of window. So mouseenter and mouseleave still keep getting hit

Comment: to explain better keep the mouse in the path of the rectangle movement, then move horizontally from result window to javascript window in your fiddle. So the last recorded movement of mouse points to left most point in ur result window. When the rectangle resets or begins its journey again from left the mouse enter and leave will get hit.

Comment: @Wishy I've updated the answer. A mouseleave-event on the wrapper div will counter this behaviour.

Comment: perfect. Lol i tried a longer approach but had problems when mouse was moved out faster. Ur updates answer should work perfect
http://jsfiddle.net/wishy/ywr1kb2z/1/